# Array of buttons WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to add an array of buttons created in the code of my apps to the UI. It'll be a kind of a grid of buttons. How can i do it in Windows Phone? I tried different ways but i didn't make it.
Thanks

Comment: one or twodimensional, horizontal or vertical array of buttons?

Comment: two dimensional array. I want to arrange it like in a calculator

Answer (score 1):

Create a `StackPanel` (or `Grid` or some other panel type that can layout your controls according to your specification).

Create all you buttons (you can put them in a `List<Button>` to keep track of them) and add each button to `StackPanel.Children`.

**Edit**
If you put your `Button`s in a `Grid` and want to put each `Button` in a separate column you need to set the attached property `Grid.Column`

```
Button b = new Button();
grid.Children.Add(b);
b.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1); // 1 is column 1, etc.
```

Comment: I tried it and i used a Grid but one button took the whole space of the grid. I want to make an 2D array that can be accessed by: Array[i][j]

Comment: @geeko, you need to set the number of rows and columns of the grid too.

Comment: and it's the same for line property i suppose because i want an 2D array. If yes would it be like this: <br/> <pre><code>                            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                {
                    b[i, j] = new Button();
                    b[i, j].SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, i);
                    b[i, j].SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, j);                    
                    grid.Children.Add(b[i, j]);
                }</code></pre> <br/> How do i set the number of columns and lines